# Проблемы с выводом символов

Tags: c++, c, winapi, вывод

Я использую цикл для вывода числа к*1.57 на каждом пересечении линий,но мне вместо этого выводятся китайские символы,помогите решить проблему,пожалуйста.Думаю,что проблема либо в sprintf,либо в преобразовании LPCWSTR,но без него не компилируется.

```
    float k;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20;i++)
    {
        k = 0;
        k = 1.57*i;
        char buff[100];
        sprintf(buff, "%f", k);
        TextOut(hdc, x0 + dx*i*1.57, yc, (LPCWSTR)buff, 5);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPCWSTR` — это `wchar_t`. Используйте буфер `wchar_t` и `wsprintf`, либо `TextOutA`.

Comment: Спасибо,работает